# I get an error when I execute npm install go-ipfs

Tags: npm-install, ipfs

I am running `npm install go-ipfs` error，

```
downloading https://dist.ipfs.io/go-ipfs/v0.4.18/go-ipfs_v0.4.18_linux-amd64.tar.gz
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 31.13.80.1:443
Download failed!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! go-ipfs-dep@0.4.18 install: `node src/bin.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the go-ipfs-dep@0.4.18 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zcy/.npm/_logs/2019-01-13T13_37_11_707Z-debug.log
```

Why is this problem, I can't seem to be connected to the network, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it myself and worked properly:

````
```
» npm i go-ipfs-dep

> go-ipfs-dep@0.4.18 install /Users/imp/code/sandbox/node_modules/go-ipfs-dep
> node src/bin.js

Downloading https://dist.ipfs.io/go-ipfs/v0.4.18/go-ipfs_v0.4.18_darwin-amd64.tar.gz
Downloaded ipfs_v0.4.18_darwin-amd64.tar.gz
Installed go-ipfs v0.4.18 darwin-amd64 to /Users/imp/code/sandbox/node_modules/go-ipfs-dep/go-ipfs/
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/imp/code/sandbox/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/imp/code/sandbox/package.json'
npm WARN sandbox No description
npm WARN sandbox No repository field.
npm WARN sandbox No README data
npm WARN sandbox No license field.

+ go-ipfs-dep@0.4.18
updated 1 package and audited 1208 packages in 14.167s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```
````

Can you open https://dist.ipfs.io/ on your browser? Does it work to download from there?

It might have been a service hiccup but also it might be an issue on your network. Let me know if you try again and still find issues.

Comment: yes, there is a problem, I use the gateway to download IPFS, butnpm ERR! path /home/zcy/node_modules/go-ipfs/node_modules/go-platform
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/home/zcy/node_modules/go-ipfs/node_modules/go-platform'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS seems to be resolving dist.ipfs.io to 31.13.80.1, which is an IP address controlled by Facebook (https://bgp.he.net/net/31.13.80.0/24), not the IPFS project. That would not be an IP address it would ever resolve to, so I would check with your DNS resolver or your /etc/hosts and see if there's something weird going on there.

Perhaps try switching to a different DNS resolver and see if it fixes it: https://1.1.1.1/

Comment: I still have a problem, please see my answer below.